# Computing binomial coefficients mod 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Computing binomial coefficients $n\choose k$ mod $2$ is relatively easy. It is $1$ if and only if the $1$'s in the binary expansion of $k$ are a subset of the $1$'s in the binary expansion of $n$. I would like to show that if $a, b, c$ are positive numbers, and ${{a+b}\choose{a}} = 1$ mod $2$, then ${{a+b-c}\choose {a+c}} = 1$ mod $2$. I have trouble working with binary expansion.

Comment: Should the $a$ be $c$ in the second binomial coefficient? As stated, the result is wrong.

Comment: Yes sorry, I made a mistake.

Comment: As currently stated:  doesn't $a=2$, $b=4$, $c=1$ give a counterexample?

Comment: Ok thank you, I see that it does not work. Sorry!